# Static methods are evil, then how come Laravel uses so much static calls?

Tags: php, laravel, tdd

If you have been into test-driven driven development especially in PHP, you probably know that static methods are hard to test. Mocking static calls have been deprecated with PHPUnit.

How to do guys mock static calls? And if statics are bad for TDD, how Laravel tests all its static calls?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Laravel uses a lot of facades, but you can easily [test everything](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing). I'd recommend you to read a "Laravel Testing Decoded" by Jeffrey Way, it will answer all of your questions.

If you don't want to use facades, you don't have to, because Laravel offers a lot of global helpers (like `redirect()` for `Redirect::`, `auth()` for `Auth::`, `session()` for `Session::` etc). Also, you can always use DI:

```
public function index(User $user)
{
    $users = $user->all();
```

Instead of:

```
$users = User::all();
```

Comment: Thank you Alexi. That's exactly what I wanted to hear!

Comment: Also another reasonable answer is that Laravel doesn't really follow good design rules.

Comment: Using global state really makes code hard to understand. I kind of wonder did Laravel try to make peace with bad coders but also encourage good coders to use it? it seems like all those methods can be called both ways... to better understand why Global state is evil see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI